# Clase con función estática no se encuentra PHP

Tags: php7, static

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual intento llamar a una función estática.

**Clase Routes.php**

```
<?php
Route::set("grettings", function() {
    echo "hola";
});
?>
```

Sin embargo cuando intento llamar a esta función me arroja error de que no encuentra la clase Route, la clase Route esta dentro de otra carpeta y aunque he probado en tenerla al mimo nivel que la clase Routes.php, no he tenido suerte.

**Clase Route.php** esta dentro de una carpeta llamada clases

```
<?php
class Route {
    public static $routes = array();
    
    public static function set($route, $function) {
        self::$routes[] = $route;

        if(in_array($route, self::$routes)) {
            return call_user_func($function);
        }
        
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Te hace falta importar con `require_once` por ejemplo el archivo `Route` a donde planeas usarlo o si estas trabajando (al margen de que no se si estas trabajando la carga de clases de algún otro modo)

Answer (score 0):

normalmente la carga de clases es algo que no gestionamos, debido al uso de autoloads, como el que trae Composer, sin embargo es interesante hacer uno para aprender sobre su funcionamiento.

La carga se realiza a partir de punto de entrada, normalmente un index.php en el directorio principal de la aplicación, las rutas son relativas a este directorio y combiene usar variables "mágicas" para encontrar la ubicación correcta (**DIR** y **FILE**).

Es fácil de entender con un ejemplo, creo lo siguiente en el directorio de ejecución de mi servidor:

```
prueba-classes
  |-- index.php
  |-- app/
        |--classes
             |-- Foo.php
```

"index.php" es el punto de entrada y el directorio "prueba-classes" el directorio raiz del proyecto.

Ahora pongo lo siguiente en "index.php":

```
<?php

echo 'Hola desde "index.php" <br>';
echo 'Estoy en ' . __DIR__ . '<br>';

require __DIR__ . '/app/classes/Foo.php';
```

Y en "Foo.php":

```
<?php

echo 'Hola desde "Foo.php" <br>';
echo 'Estoy en ' . __DIR__ . '<br>';
```

Al cargar en el navegador, en mi caso yo veo:

```
Hola desde "index.php"
Estoy en /var/www/html/PHP/load-classes
Hola desde "Foo.php"
Estoy en /var/www/html/PHP/load-classes/app/classes
```

La pregunta es sobre clases, es un poco lo mismo, aunque para las clases "deberíamos" añadir namespaces... Cambio el contenido de los ficheros.

En "index.php":

```
<?php

echo 'Hola desde "index.php" <br>';
echo 'Estoy en ' . __DIR__ . '<br>';

require __DIR__ . '/app/classes/Foo.php';

new App\Classes\Foo();
```

En "Foo.php":

```
<?php

namespace App\Classes;

class Foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Hola desde "Foo.php" <br>';
        echo 'Estoy en ' . __DIR__ . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Al cargar, tengo el mismo resultado:

```
Hola desde "index.php"
Estoy en /var/www/html/PHP/load-classes
Hola desde "Foo.php"
Estoy en /var/www/html/PHP/load-classes/app/classes
```

Normalmente cuando una clase no se encuentra es porque no esta el fichero,
el nombre de la clase o del fichero están mal escritos, incluyendo el namespace, etc.

Un método que puede ayudar es: [class_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.class-exists.php).